# Html.LabelFor does not use Name from DisplayAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelmetadata

I have a model like this

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PageMetadataMetadata))]
public class PageMetadata : IPageMetadata {
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and my metadata class like this

```
internal class PageMetadataMetadata {
    [Display(Name = "Title", Order = 10, Prompt = "My awesome page")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name_Required")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I use this model in my view I cannot get it to use the name from my DisplayAttribute?

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentModel.Metadata.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

With [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx), you have to set also the `ResourceType`. If you don't want to use localization try using [DisplayNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx).

Comment: I know about the localization but the problem here is that I must use EditorForModel to get the proper name from displayattribute och displaynameattribute

Comment: have you tried setting the resourcetype that is missin in your model? what happend? with only displayattribute?

Comment: I have tried with resourcetype and with dislayname attribute but none of this works, it still uses the property name for label text

Comment: try looking at this article about ModelMetadataProviders http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=715